# Speed up plotting dates in matplotlib

Tags: performance, date, matplotlib

I have this code, which works; however python takes ages if its asked to use dates rather than numbers on the x axis.

```
prices_list = [eval(price_line[x]) for x in range(0, len(price_line))]  # 
xs = [n for n in range(0,len(prices_list))]
y_but, yf= fltflt(xs, prices_list)
ddo = [datetime.strptime(dtes[x], "%Y-%m-%d").date() for x in range(0, len(dtes))]
date1 = ddo[0] 
date2 = ddo[len(ddo) - 1] 
ax1 = pl.subplot(1,1,1)
ax1.plot(ddo,prices_list, 'b')
ax1.grid(True)
ax1.plot(ddo,yf, 'r') 
pl.xticks(ddo,rotation=45)
ax1.set_xlim( [date1, date2] )
ax1.set_ylim([min(prices_list), max(prices_list)])
pl.title(epics[e])
pl.show()
```

The x data spans 5 to 10 years and has 1500 - 3000 dates. I only want to plot the years, so only need 5 to 10 x ticks. Plotting years is more informative than numbers, but considerably slower. Any suggestions how to speed things up?

Answer (score 1):

You could use a `matplotlib.dates.AutoDateLocator` with a max-number-of-ticks, or use a `matplotlib.dates.YearLocator` with a base multiple (tick every 5 years, every 1000, whatever). The most complicated version is a `RRuleLocator` which gives complicated calendar control.

See the [example](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/date_demo_rrule.html) of the RRule; the general principle is

1)  specify locator, formatter

```
loc = matplotlib.dates.RRuleLocator(rule)
formatter = matplotlib.dates.DateFormatter('%m/%d/%y')
```

2) make an axes and use the locator, formatter

```
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(loc)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```